# SQL table data to HTML table using jQuery MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, vba, model-view-controller

I am trying to get the SQL table details to HTML table for that, what I've done is I have created a controller and model and view. I also created the SQL table with fields of voucher number and amount. Here is how I created the controller here I have referenced the model, model demo

```
<HttpGet>
Function GetSalesDetail(invoiceId As String) As JsonResult
    Dim listSalesDetail As List(Of Hashtable) = New ModelDemo().GetSalesDetail(invoiceId)
    Return Json(listSalesDetail, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
End Function
```

the model demo code consists of SQL connection

```
Public Function GetSalesDetail(invoiceId As String) As List(Of Hashtable)
    Dim listSalesDetail As List(Of Hashtable) = New List(Of Hashtable)
    Dim arraySalesDetail As Hashtable
    'Dim arraySalesDetail As Dictionary(Of String, String) '**Associative array**'
    Dim conn = New SqlConnection(connStringLocal)
    conn.Open()
    Using query = New SqlCommand("SELECT vchNum,productName,Qty,Price,Amount,total FROM BillDetails 
    WHERE vchNum='" & invoiceId & "'", conn)
        Using resultSet = query.ExecuteReader
            If resultSet.HasRows Then
                While resultSet.Read()
                    'arraySalesDetail = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
                    arraySalesDetail = New Hashtable
                    arraySalesDetail.Add("vchNum", resultSet("vchNum"))
                    arraySalesDetail.Add("ProductName", resultSet("ProductName"))
                    arraySalesDetail.Add("Qty", resultSet("Qty"))
                    arraySalesDetail.Add("Price", resultSet("Price"))
                    arraySalesDetail.Add("Amount", resultSet("Amount"))
                    arraySalesDetail.Add("total", resultSet("total"))
                    listSalesDetail.Add(arraySalesDetail)
                End While
            End If
                resultSet.Close()
                'resultSet = Nothing
            End Using
        End Using
        conn.Close()
        Return listSalesDetail
    End Function
```

the `document.load` function consists of

```
$.get('@Url.Content("~")Home/GetSalesDetail', {
    invoiceId: salesHeaderData.invoiceId
  })
  .done(function(salesDetailData) {
    for (var j = 0; j < salesDetailData.length; j++) {
      var input = {};
      console.log("Loop for list details");
      $('input[name="ProductName"]').val(salesDetailData.ProductName);
      $('input[name="Qty"').val(salesDetailData.Qty);
      $('input[name="Price"').val(salesDetailData.Price);
    }
  })
```

and index html consists of

```
 <table id="detailTable">
 <thead><tr><th>ProductName</th><th>Qty</th><th>Price</th></tr></thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><input name="ProductName"></td>
    <td><input name="Qty"></td>
    <td><input name="Price">
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

and this is how I tried. Can anyone help the load function not working?

Comment: Try iterating the data over jQuery and create table rows. And finally append the data to the body

Comment: Whether the request hit on the server side?

Comment: yes it does while i retrieve i found the result not shown

Comment: can you switch to razor component, secondly you have tagged your question as using VBA, but it is using vb.net

Comment: no later i have to convert this to phonegap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's possible to remove the inputs you can do it like this:

```
    var html = '';      
    $.each(salesDetailData, function (i, item) {

    html += '<tr><td>' + item.ProductName + '</td><td>' + item.Qty + '</td><td>' + item.Price + '</td></tr>';    

   })
  $('tbody').append(html);
```

your html will look like this:

```
    <table id="detailTable">
      <thead><tr><th>ProductName</th><th>Qty</th><th>Price</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```